# Query formula to import the data from multiple tab sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using a `query` to import the data from multiple sheets, however, the formula is skipping empty cells. Is it possible to not skip empty cells and keep the data in the correct cell on the Master?
Here is formula I am using:

```
=query({
'nff1'!A2:A;
'nff2'!A2:A;
'nff3'!A2:A;
'nff4'!A2:A;
'nff5'!A2:A;
'nff6'!A2:A;
'nff7'!A2:A},
"Select * where Col1 is not null ")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

To keep all rows, including completely blank rows, just leave out the `query()` wrapper, like this:

`={ nff1!A2:A; nff2!A2:A; nff3!A2:A; nff4!A2:A; nff5!A2:A; nff6!A2:A; nff7!A2:A }`

To merge the data, including phone numbers, use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) like this:

```
=query( 
  { 
    { 
      'ff1'!G2:G;
      'ff2'!G2:G;
      'ff3'!A2:A;
      'ff4'!E2:E 
    }, 
    { 
      'ff1'!A2:A;
      'ff2'!A2:A;
      'ff3'!B2:B;
      'ff4'!A2:A 
    }, 
    { 
      'ff1'!C2:C;
      'ff2'!C2:C;
      'ff3'!C2:C;
      'ff4'!B2:B 
    }, 
    { 
      'ff1'!X2:X;
      'ff2'!D2:D;
      'ff3'!D2:D;
      'ff4'!X2:X 
    } 
  },
  "where Col1 is not null", 
  0 
)
```

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162fLIDAQunby5NmqJ5Who_oX01gBg13CtXpikn-95yY/edit?userstoinvite=umer80854%40gmail.com#gid=1993163632) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Going forward, you may want to standardize the layout on individual sheets.

Comment: Or, if the OP wants the `query` for some reason, either delete the entire `select` clause OR delete the `where` clause. Either way, as you point out, there is a big risk of large gaps between data if there are lots of blank rows at the bottom of sheets.

Comment: not working still

Comment: I need a phone but it's not coming right don't leave empty cell where no entry 
here is my sheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162fLIDAQunby5NmqJ5Who_oX01gBg13CtXpikn-95yY/edit?userstoinvite=umer80854%40gmail.com#gid=0

Comment: Edited the answer. If you need more help, show your _hand-entered_ expected results in the sample spreadsheet.